# How can I play multiple audio clips with angularjs? Can I pick the file from my html?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, audio

New to angular and coding, I'm trying to build a site that can play multiple short audio clips with angularjs. In an attempt to trim down my controller, I first all of my audio files stored in a service like so:

```
service('audioService', function() {
  this.clip1 = new Audio(pathtofile);
  this.clip2 = new Audio(pathtofile);
  etc
});
```

I then have in my main controller:

```
$scope.audioFiles = audioService;
$scope.audioPlay = function(clip) {
  clip.play();
};
```

Finally, I'm trying to get my audio files to play by:

```
ng-click="audioPlay(audioFiles.clip1)"
```

But this all returns an error that I'm trying to access the DOM node incorrectly, which truth be told I don't entirely understand. I think(tried several configurations for the past couple of hours) was able to get audio to play once when I fed audioFiles.clip1 to the function from inside the controller, but I can't seem to choose the file from html. I'd like to do this because the final project is playing these short audio clips from multiple html "slides" I'm shuffling through with ng-view. They are all 1-3 seconds, so I don't need to worry about any other controls besides play.

Comment: do you use a `select` list or a `checkbox` of some sort to display the options of all clips?

Comment: The layout is a sentence with a button after it. The button plays a sound clip of the entire sentence, while clicking on individual words plays a sound clip of that word. At least that's the end goal.

Answer (score 1):

So I think I figured it out. I pulled my $scope.audioPlay into a seperate player service. That service looks like this:

```
dojo.factory('player', function(audio, $rootScope) {
var player = {

    play: function(clip) {
        audio.src = clip;
        audio.play();
        player.playing = true;
    },
    stop: function() {
        if (player.playing) {
            audio.pause();
            player.playing = false;
            player.current = null;
        }
    }
};
audio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    $rootScope.$apply(player.stop());
});
return player;
});
```

I then set my $scope.audioPlay to player.play, having injected both my audio file service and my player service into my controller. Now my html file works exactly the way I want it to.